# Get drive power state without waking it up

Tags: linux, hard-drive, electrical-power

Is there any way how to determine whether some drive is sleeping without occasionally waking it up? I have tried `hdparm -C` and `smartctl -i` but both of them actually wake it up when its already sleeping.

I need to set up a script that regularly checks the drive states and sets them asleep at certain times in case they are not sleeping already. (In fact that calling `hdparm -Y` on a sleeping drive actually wakes it up!).

Comment: I imagine that, since you're polling the drive's firmware, it needs to wake up to activate that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using **standby** (`hdparm -y`) mode instead of **sleep** (`hdparm -Y`). In this mode issuing `hdparm -C` or `smartctl --nocheck standby -i` won't wake up drive.

Comment: What's the exact difference between standby mode and sleep mode? In terms of power consumption.

Comment: I don't know but I suspect that difference is minimal because in both modes drive is spun down.

Comment: 3. Standby – The device is capable of responding to commands but the device may take longer (up
to 30 seconds) to complete commands than in the Idle mode. Power consumption is reduced
from that of Idle mode. If a hard drive is present, it is spun down.
4. Sleep – This is the lowest power mode. The device interface is typically inactive and, if a hard
drive is present, the drive is spun down. The device will exit the Sleep mode only after receiving a
reset. Wake up time can be as long as 30 seconds. Quote from `SATA Power Management: It’s Good to Be Green`